# Analytically finding intersection points and bounds between a cylinder and two planes

Tags: integration, geometry, volume, cylindrical-coordinates

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and the planes $x + y + z = 1$ and $4x + 2y + z = 7$.

---

I am able to find the radius of the cylinder by switching to cylindrical coordinates.

Let $x = \rho \cos(\theta)$, $y = \rho \sin(\theta)$, $z = \zeta$ $\forall \rho \ge 0, \theta \in [0, 2\pi], \zeta \in \mathbb{R}$.

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a cylinder of radius $1$.

$\therefore \rho^2 \cos^2(\theta) + \rho^2\sin^2(\theta) = 1$

$\implies \rho^2 = 1$

$\therefore 0 \le \rho \le 1$ since $\rho \ge 0$

But this is only within the context of the cylinder. Usually, I would find the intersection points between the objects and then find the limits of integration. However, in this case, I can't find a way to equate the planes with the cylinder and algebraically manipulate the equation to find intersection points and limits of integration. Of course, we could find all of these graphically by drawing a diagram, but, for the purpose of generality, I am interested in solving these problems analytically.

I'm out of ideas and unsure of how to proceed with calculations in such a way that will enable me to analytically determine the intersection points and limits between these 3 objects. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to demonstrate how to go about this and explain the reasoning behind each step so that I may learn to do it for myself in the future.

Comment: What are intersection points of plane $x + y + z = 1$ with axis' $x$, $y$, $z$?

Comment: @MyGlasses thanks for the response. The intersection with respect to, for instance, the z-axis would be $z = 1 - x - y$. But that's not necessarily the intersection point with the cylinder?

Comment: I read you post again, I found you have the answer and I want to say in many problems we need a little geometry and those can't be solved with pure analytically ways.

Comment: @MyGlasses but that can't be true; otherwise, we wouldn't be able to do mathematics above 3-dimensions! And I'm not saying I want to exclude geometrical concepts; rather, I want to solve the problem without necessarily graphing the object.

Comment: Right. I mean we need some imagination to start. In this problem, the plane $x+y+z=1$ intersect axis' in $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. other plane $4x+2y+z=7$ intersect axis' in $(\frac74,0,0)$, $(0,(\frac72,0)$ and $(0,0,7)$. These point found analytically but if we couldnot image in our mind, It's hard to see that the plane $4x+2y+z=7$ is above $x+y+z=1$ and imagine help us very much **here**!.

Comment: The limits of integration on $\rho$ are $0$ to $1$. The limits on $\theta$ are $0$ to $2\pi$. The limits on $z$ are $1 - \rho\cos\theta - \rho\sin\theta$ and $7 - 4\rho\cos\theta - 2\rho\sin\theta$. Obviously, you'll have to integrate over $z$ first, but it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've managed to solve this problem analytically.

We want to find the volume of the solid bounded by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and the planes $x + y + z = 1$ and $4x + 2y + z = 7$.

Since we are dealing with a cylinder, we will convert to cylindrical coordinates.

Let $x = \rho \cos(\theta)$, $y = \rho \sin(\theta)$, $z = \zeta$ $\forall \rho \ge 0, \theta \in [0, 2\pi], \zeta \in \mathbb{R}$.

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a cylinder of radius $1$.

$\therefore \rho^2 \cos^2(\theta) + \rho^2\sin^2(\theta) = 1$

$\implies \rho^2 = 1$

$\therefore 0 \le \rho \le 1$ since $\rho \ge 0$

We now know that $\theta \in [0, 2\pi], \rho \in [0, 1]$. Therefore, the only bounds that remain to be found are those for $\zeta$.

$x + y + z = 1$

$\therefore \rho \cos(\theta) + \rho \sin(\theta) + \zeta = 1$

$\implies \zeta = 1 - \rho \cos(\theta) - \rho \sin(\theta)$

$4x + 2y + z = 7$

$\therefore 4\rho \cos(\theta) + 2\rho \sin(\theta) + \zeta = 7$

$\implies \zeta = 7 - 4\rho \cos(\theta) - 2\rho \sin(\theta)$

Therefore, the bounds for $\zeta$ are $\zeta = 7 - 4\rho \cos(\theta) - 2\rho \sin(\theta)$ and $\zeta = 1 - \rho \cos(\theta) - \rho \sin(\theta)$.

However, we still need to know which value of $\zeta$ is the upper limit and which is the lower limit. If we draw a diagram, then we will be able to see that $\zeta = 7 - 4\rho \cos(\theta) - 2\rho \sin(\theta)$ is the upper limit. But how can we find this analytically?

We know that $\rho \in [0, 1]$, $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$.

If $\rho = 0$, then $\zeta = 1$ and $\zeta = 7$.

If $\rho = 1$ and $\theta = 0$, then $\zeta = 0$ and $\zeta = 3$.

If $\rho = 1$ and $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, then $\zeta = 0$ and $\zeta = 5$.

If $\rho = 1$ and $\theta = \pi$, then $\zeta = 2$ and $\zeta = 11$.

If $\rho = 1$ and $\theta = \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$, then $\zeta = 2$ and $\zeta = 9$.

$\therefore D = \{(\rho, \theta, \zeta) \mid 0 \le \rho \le 1, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 1 - \rho \cos(\theta) - \rho \sin(\theta) \le \zeta \le 7 - 4\rho \cos(\theta) - 2\rho \sin(\theta) \}$

$\int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\rho = 0}^{1} \int_{1 - \rho \cos(\theta) - \rho \sin(\theta)}^{7 - 4\rho \cos(\theta) - 2\rho \sin(\theta)} (1 \cdot \rho) d\zeta d\rho d\theta$ where $\rho$ in the integrand is the scaling factor for the linear transformation from xy-coordinates to cylindrical coordinates.

$= 6\pi$